# "Studying PhD at the university" or "studying PhD in the university"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-in

Which of these two sentences is correct:

> 1. I am studying PhD *at* the university.
> 2. I am studying PhD *in* the university.

Should I use "at" or "in"? Or is there no difference?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> 1. I am studying PhD at the university.
> 2. I am studying PhD in the university.

In the above, both sentences are wrong. Inserting *for a* between *studying*  and *PhD* would make sentence 1. correct. Sentence 2. would still be wrong, as *in* is the wrong preposition to use in this case:

> 1. I am studying for a PhD at the university. [Correct]
> 2. I am studying for a PhD in the university. [Wrong]

This is not to say that the construction *in the university* is inherently wrong. There are certainly some contexts where this would be the correct form to use. For instance:

> - The monument is in the university.
> - He is in the university.

It is not always easy to come up with a rule to determine the choice between *at* and *in*. Some cases are clear cut, as in my first round of examples below. Others are not always so, as in my second batch of examples, for speakers tend to leave a lot of things implied in speech and in writing. Hopefully, you will be able to infer these rules from my examples.

In academic contexts, use *at* when referring to the institution in general or to a specific one. Note, however, that one would use *in* for *graduate school* or *college* (largely American context). The construction *in university* is also correct (largely British):

> - I am studying for a PhD *at* the university.
> - I'm *at* Oxford for a PhD.
> - I'm studying for a PhD *in* graduate school.
> - I'm currently *in* grad school for a PhD.
> - I'm a sophomore *in* college.
> - I'm *in* university for a PhD.
> - I am studying for a PhD *at* Harvard.
> - I am studying for a PhD *at* the Indian Institute of Technology in Delhi.
> - I'm a PhD student *at* ETH, Zurich.
> - I'm *at* King's College, London.
> - I'm a junior *at* Williams College.

I should point out that *in college* and *in university* are rather colloquial constructions, but that's why they're used in everyday situations! In more formal contexts, it would be better to use *at college/ at university*.

More examples using *school*, *department* and *faculty* both explicitly and implicitly. Generally, *in* is used for *department*, while *at* is used for *faculty*:

> - I'm studying for a PhD *in* the physics department.
> - I'm *in* physics *at* MIT.
> - He's a professor *in* the Department of Biology *at* Harvard.
> - Are you the only assistant professor *in* this department?
> - I'm a PhD student *at* the Faculty of Social Sciences *in* the University of Copenhagen.
> - She's a professor *at* the Faculty of Arts and Sciences.
> - My son is a lecturer *in* criminology *at* the Faculty of Law.
> - I'm a PhD student *at* the Cape Town University Faculty of Law.
> - I am *in* the School of Engineering for a PhD.
> - He's a professor *in* Biological Sciences *at* Cambridge.
> - I am a PhD student *at* the Yale School of Architecture.
> - I'm studying for a PhD *in* the law school *at* Harvard.
> - I'm a PhD student *at* Harvard Law [School].

---

*NB: I did not look up information from any grammar book. These are just examples I came up with based on my experiences as a native speaker, general observations of usage, and what sounds right!*

Comment: (Although if they're at Oxford, they're studying for a DPhil rather than a PhD.)

Comment: It's quite difficult to find a pattern in the above. Especially "at Harvard Law School" vs "in the law school at Harvard" : this would tend to show that *at* would be used when we give a name that is specific to the place? Your examples only make the difference for a name of place, which doesn't completely solve the issue. If the law school takes a unique name, would one say "at the Barack Obama Law School"? And then would you add "at Harvard", or rather "in Harvard [University]", and would it be not to duplicate the "at" or because it is this specific named department/school which is "in" it?

Answer (score 14):

In the UK we'd be most likely to say:

> I am studying **for a** PhD **at** the university.

Furthermore, the *the* would be dropped if we weren't emphasising a specific university.

"**In** the university" would usually be understood to mean "physically inside the university buildings".

Comment: United States usage is precisely the same, though we generally lack "at university"...we would say "at college".