# Which one is more correct: "works at a university" or "works in a university"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-in

> My relative is a fairly big academic and works **at** a university.

Is this correct? or should I have used **in** instead?

Comment: Related: [“Studying PhD at the university” or “studying PhD in the university”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/studying-phd-at-the-university-or-studying-phd-in-the-university)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My relative is a fairly big academic and works *at* a university

is correct.

> My relative is a fairly big academic and works *in* a university

is wrong.

See a similar example at [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/university).

Comment: I'm not sure I would definitively say that using "in" is wrong because a dictionary doesn't use it in one of the examples for the noun "university". Said dictionary has an entry for "in" that seems like a valid use for this case: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/in_3

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice: This was a very quick answer. Certainly, there are cases where the construction *in a university* would be correct. In this case/context, however, *in a university* is absolutely wrong. I just did not have the time to come with a reason. In fact, the only reason I can think of is *at* is simply the correct preposition to use here. I only cited the dictionary example to lend more credibility to my answer, as the example's context is exactly the same as the one here.

Comment: My appologies for being abrasive in my first comment.  Let me say that I agree that using "at" seems like the more natural/appropriate choice here, and your citation of the dictionary's example does back that up.  I think I mistook your citation as evidence that using "in" is wrong, which may not be what you intended.  Personally, I don't really agree that using "in" is absolutely wrong for this case, although I don't have any evidence that suggests one way or the other whether it is acceptable.

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice: Oh, no worries; no offense taken, at all, although I admit that my rejoinder may have been slightly curt. And I do agree: *absolutely* is too strong a modifier. Indeed, evidence is hard to find :)

Comment: I completely disagree that it is "absolutely wrong". There is no way to determine what this person is trying to say without proper context. Counter-example: `My friend is a fairly big academic and works outside mainstream academia in the mountains of Tibet doing geological research. However, my relative is also a fairly big academic and works in a university.`

Answer (score 2):

The quoted sentence is fine.

'In' is usually used when speaking about the general kind of work someone does, e.g.

> My father works **in** telecommunications.

but

> My father works **at** the telephone exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'in' is not just plain wrong - although in that context it does sound it. I would possibly use 'in' if I meant that he *works* there, but is not directly involved in the university establishment, for example someone who is for whatever reason doing an unrelated job but using the university for accommodation, or a cleaner etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use "**at**" in that case. It's completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

AT university

- *My son studies at a university*.
- *My brother teaches English at a university.*

But...

- *My friend Sohan is a painter. He is now working* ***in*** *a university.*

A student studies or a teacher works AT a university while a person not directly involved with studying or teaching for which a university exists, like a carpenter or a painter, works IN a university. At the same time you should use *at* when the name of the university is mentioned:

> Unfortunately, I did not get a chance to study **at** University Oxford.