# "Employment with" vs. "employment at"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-with

Which of the following options are correct?

> - [Some context] that is relevant to my employment **with** the company.
> - [Some context] that is relevant to my employment **at** the company.

Comment: Related: [Which one is more correct: "works at a university" or "works in a university"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/which-one-is-more-correct-works-at-a-university-or-works-in-a-university)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical distinction between the two options is that with *with* a company strongly implies that you work *for* them. Working *at* a company could imply that you are simply there doing work on their building or network or something like that:

> I am working at Starbucks fixing their cash registers.
>
> I work at Starbucks because they have free internet.

But this isn't a necessary distinction. Both *work with* and *work at* usually mean that you *work for* the company and, typically, people say "I work at Starbucks." *With* sounds a bit more formal to me and has a more "us" quality about it. *At* feels less formal and feels more like the company is disembodied or distant.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, my usage of the phrase was within a legal document. In that context, I think 'with' avoids the ambiguity you mention when using 'at'.