# "At/In the Summer Olympics"

Tags: differences, prepositions, at-in

### !

I found this to be strange: in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics),

> Russia **at** the 2008 Summer Olympics
>   Russia competed **at** the 2008 Summer Olympics

How different is the meaning if *at* is changed to *in*?

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66295/in-college-versus-at-college-versus-at-university

Answer (score 6):

"I was **at** the venues of the 2008 Olympics" can be shortened to "I was at the 2008 Olympics".

"I participated **in** the events of the 2008 Olympics" can be shorted to "I was in the 2008 Olympics".

In your example, both are fine, especially seeing as the context clearly describes that Russia were **at** the venues participating.

Answer (score 6):

My friend, Philippe, a championship fencer, is **at** the London 2012 Summer Olympics.

However, he is attending as a spectator, and is therefore not **in** the London 2012 Summer Olympics.

SUPPLEMENT: While both **at** and **in** may be correct when the referenced person/entity was *present* and *competed*, they are not interchangable when both did not occur. I think it is tautological that anyone **in** the Olympics must be **at** the Olympics (since you can't phone it **in**), but the obverse is not so.

Comment: The second example doesn't seem to work seeing as Russia competed _at_ the 2008 Summer Olympics.

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is no substantial difference if ***at*** is substituted by ***in***. However ***at*** conveys ambiguity when not used with a nation since, for example, a spectator can also be ***at*** but not ***in***.

Comment: I would argue that, if you described a nation as being **at** the Olympics, most would assume participation.  I should add that I agree with your answer though.

Comment: @Ste Quite right, the ambiguity confused me!

Comment: Then, the original example was not well written?

Comment: @rednow The original was fine. I was referring to my answer which I subsequently edited to make clearer.