# "When I was in college..." Do you really mean college? Or university?

Tags: american-english, word-usage

When someone in the US says "When I was in college..."  he can mean "college" but he can also mean "university", so I've been told. If that's true, how can we know which one he is talking about?  If I say my daughter is off to college, can it really mean either one?

Comment: If somebody says *"when I was in college"*, it means that he was working towards a bachelor's degree. Does it matter whether he was at an institution that calls itself a *"college"*, a *"university"*, an *"institute"*, or a *"school"*?

Comment: @PeterShor In this case I understand a medical graduate, or a dentist, would never say "when I was in college" if he wants to refer to the time he was in Medical School.  Am I right ?

Comment: @Peter: That's what I think too. I usually speak of when I was *at college* because [mine wasn't called a "university"](http://www.port.ac.uk/) until after I left. But the younger generation in the UK often go to "[sixth-form] colleges" now, where they spend two years getting the necessary qualifications to start a degree (normally, at age 18). So both usages are now possible here.

Comment: @Luis No, that's not right. He would say "When I was in medical school". Peter is right that college means undergraduate program.

Comment: @Jeremy I think you misunderstood my comment.

Comment: @Luis what do you understand to be the difference between "college" and "university"? Your question is probably confusing a lot of Americans because we're not aware of the difference, or at least can't understand why one might want to distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: A note to Americans, in some parts of the world "college" means "senior high". You certainly don't go to college for a bachelors degree - you go to university for that. Then again, due to American influence I've started seeing newer places of higher education calling themselves "college" and offering bachelors and masters degree.

Comment: @slebetman However there is something of a prejudice against UK degree offering institutions which are not called universities. University is a protected word and implies a high standard regulation of the courses, the word college can be used by anyone and though they may offer degrees they are rarely considered "proper" higher education in the UK (note this is not my personal opinion, just what I have experienced widely in British academia) However I also second, here college means 16-18 pre-university, university starts at 18.

Comment: In Canada, a college is what we in the US call a community college, is more trade-oriented that academically oriented, and does not typically grant 4-year degrees.  I don't know if there are Canadian equivalents to the liberal arts college that offers only undergraduate education, but grants bachelors degrees.

Comment: In London there is _University College London_, which is of course not a college in the usual British sense, but more like an Oxbridge college, which is a different thing again. And I took my son to an open day at my _alma mater_, Edinburgh University, the other day. The faculties of science and engineering are now collectively _The College of Science and Engineering_, and the former departments (physics, maths, etc) are _schools_ within that. It's an infinitely flexible language.

Comment: The undergraduate school at "Harvard University" is formally called "Harvard College".

Comment: @slebetman Still on a side note, collège in France refers to medium school. Not sure how relevant though.

Comment: In the US, there is a subset of post-secondary education called "junior colleges" or "community colleges", which grant only 2 year Associates degrees, and are usually non-residential (and frequently, students are part-time). An AA or AS degree is a bit more on the vocational training side than a general education (BA or BS) from a 4 year school. Anything 4 years and up can call itself whatever it wants to: college, institute, and university are the most common, with "school of..." not unknown.

Comment: There's also Trinity College in Dublin and Imperial College in London both offering postgrad courses and both highly prestigious and are technically universities. It's common to hear people say "I went to uni at Imperial College".

Comment: I guess Americans are the only ones who use the word consistently.

Comment: Then there is always McDonald's University.

Comment: U.S. junior colleges are often called jucos. Sometimes they have a heavy sports orientation. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Juco

Comment: @PeterShor That's a great distinction. If you're in Grad School, you don't say "College". I think you don't say College to get an associates either. We don't say "going to University" in the States, it sounds pretentious.

Comment: @Arlaud Pierre: with the big exception of the "Collège de France"...

Comment: @Jeremy I am in the US and attended a university to get my undergrad degree from a particular college within the university.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany just one opinion, but I have *never* heard of the term 'juco' in the US.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158558/difference-between-college-and-university

Comment: @KitFox  I was careful to check the "Questions that may already have your answer" dropdown so as not to waste my time. No "possible duplicate" was shown. I'm surprised that you should have found that one. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While the OP specifies the US, some of the other answers are based on other countries. I'll respond mainly regarding the US, but I'll start with some comments regarding other countries. In many countries, *college* means secondary school, following on from primary school. It would never mean that to the average American.

Technically, a US college is a venue for obtaining post-high school (post-secondary) qualifications. It could be a 2-year degree, called an Associates degree, which may or may not be vocationally-based.  You can get an AA or AS in welding, math, Spanish, etc. These colleges are usually known as *community colleges.*

The other type of college grants Bachelor's degrees (not to be confused with the bachillerato granted in many countries to what in the US would be called high school students, who are typically going on to what in the US would be called college). There are 4-year liberal arts colleges, and there are subject-oriented colleges (which are now rare).

In the US, a university would be composed of multiple colleges, including one or more bachelors colleges, as well as a grad school. You really have to offer a Masters degree to be able to call it a university.

Most Universities also offer Ph.D.s and possibly other advanced degrees (in the American academic world, we now call the MA and beyond *terminal degrees*), such as MD, JD, THD etc.

Some places, like Boston College, have chosen to keep *College* in their name, even though they are universities.

I would not say "I'm going to university"; I'd say "I'm in college" (though for my last degree I was actually taking classes in three colleges of the university).
I could say "I'm at the University of California", or "I go to Yale University", but not "I'm in university" (or "I'm in Uni") without it sounding a bit affected.

So if all I said was that my daughter was off to college, you wouldn't know if she was attending a small liberal arts school of 300 or a prestigious university, or even a local community college (but then why say she was "off to?") -- but you would know that she was studying at a level beyond high school.

People who are not in academia might use the term without knowing all these details.

Comment: Can you please add some paragraph breaks?

Comment: Many people wonder why Boston College doesn't just change its name to Boston University. They forget that there is already a Boston University only a short distance from BC.

Comment: (Note that Boston University is in Boston; BC is not.)

Comment: @PeterShor makes a great point that "Going to college" specifically refers to a Bachelor's program, not "grad school" or getting your associate's. Going for your associates is "going to school," where school is anywhere that offers an associates or certificates.

Comment: **TL;DR** they just choose the same name for random different things (;

Answer (score 27):

In the US, there is little difference between a college and a university in common speech. Generally, institutes of higher learning with smaller student bodies call themselves colleges, while larger institutions call themselves universities, but the distinction is largely cosmetic.
So you usually wouldn't know for sure, but that doesn't really matter.

In speech or writing, you would use *college* as the object of a preposition (e.g., "going to college") no matter whether the institution calls itself a college or a university; "going to university" would be understood, but sounds affected when spoken by a natural born American.

Comment: Would you say "going to college" even if you were going to medical school or law school ?

Comment: @Luis - No, never; it would be "going to medical school" (or law school, or graduate school/grad school).

Comment: I think the technical difference between a college and a university is supposed to be that the latter offers PhD's, while the former doesn't. Dunno if anyone actually *observes* this difference, mind you. (And now I see that Jeremy's answer makes exactly this point...)

Comment: I've always heard the same thing @Marthaª said. I don't know whether that distinction is universally recognized, but I'm not aware of any educational institution in the US which violates it. (ninja edit: actually I can think of a few, but they are very much a minority)

Comment: http://www.bc.edu/schools/gsas/ Boston College is an exception that comes to mind immediately.

Comment: There are exceptions in the other direction as well: for instance, none of the institutions called "California State University, [city name]" offer PhDs.  (Some of them do have masters' programs.  This distinction is enshrined in state law: only the "University of California, [city name]" institutions are allowed to have PhD programs.  I don't know if CSU institutions can have medical schools or similar.)

Comment: I went to a US University that had Institutes and Colleges in it.  The four years were still 'going to college'.

Comment: @Marthaª: In Canada the distinction was that colleges tended offer mostly trades-oriented programs and the academic programs were also very focused on application rather than theory. Colleges granted diplomas and certifications rather than bachelor's/master's degrees/PhDs. College programs tended to be shorter as well (2-3 years vs. 3-5 years for similar programs at universities). Now though, it seems the difference between the two is closing as some colleges now offer bachelor's degree programs.

Comment: When I was studying for a bachelor's degree, I considered myself to be "going to college." I would _never_ have said this at any time while studying for my master's or my Ph.D. While studying for those degrees I used to say I was "in grad school."

Comment: We also say "going to university" in Canada, by the way.

Answer (score 18):

From a technical perspective, a university is a school of higher education that offers a graduate program, while a college does not. There are exceptions to this rule, but it mostly works.

In practice, though, these are seen as VERY SIMILAR academically in the US. In terms of my education, I can get a good education at a program that only offers a 4-year bachelors and I can also get a good education at a University that offers a post-graduate degree. I get *the same education* at either type of institution. That said, universities are seen as more prestigious because post-grad work creates the opportunities for research and in general, they will offer more programs and more variety of programs. That's why Americans don't see it as important to differentiate between which of the two schools they attended.

To answer your question, you cannot tell if someone went to a university or college based on a statement like "I'm in college" or "I went to college." However, if someone is talking about post-graduate work, they will say something like "In my post-grad..." or "For my masters..." In general, there's really no reason to care whether they went to a college or a university.

Comment: Would a physician or lawyer refer to his student years as "when I was in college" ? or would it be "university" ?

Comment: It would be "med school" or "law school," respectively, unless he was referring to his time as an undergrad, and then it would usually be "college." Most people do not say "when I was at the university" in the US.

Comment: Where would "institute" fall in this spectrum?  ;)

Comment: @Izkata: Probably somewhere around [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_institute). ;-)

Comment: Harvard College might disagree with assumption that a college is a lesser body

Comment: Harvard College is a part of Harvard University. If it were not for that fact, business at Harvard College would likely be conducted a lot differently than it is now. Even for Harvard, it's more prestigious to be a university.

Comment: MIT is one of the most prestigious schools of higher education in the country. It has both undergrad and graduate programs, and offers everything from BS to PhD. But it's just a college, not a university. If you went by most of the rules for distinctions between colleges and universities, MIT would probably fit the definition of university.

Answer (score 10):

I feel compelled to add a non-US answer, as these words have quite distinct meanings in the UK.

- A University is a seat of research and tertiary (normally age 18-21) education, which awards degrees and postgraduate qualifications.
- A College can be either a place of secondary (normally age 16-18) education, with a bias toward awarding vocational qualifications. Or it can be an administrative subdivision of a University (most UK universities do not have colleges - Oxford and Cambridge famously do, and a few others have adopted that system). Which one is being spoken about when the word is used is usually obvious from the context.

The US-centric use of the word "College" as a direct alternative to "University" can cause considerable confusion to older UK English speakers, and indeed can feel annoyingly vague even to people who are aware of the different meaning across the Atlantic.

Comment: In the US, "name inflation" has become commonplace to inflate the prestige of colleges (4 year and up degrees). East Podunk Normal School became East Podunk College, and now is The University at East Podunk, all without changing that much or expanding their programs. At any rate, this further blurs any line between "college" and "university" in the US (where it wasn't that distinct before). Way back, universities usually were _systems_ comprised of two or more campuses, each a college, but it's common now to call a single institute a university.

Comment: When I did my undergraduate (in Australia), I went to a university which had 'faculties' that were made of 'schools'. College meant a residential college, basically accommodation for students along with various extra-curricular activities. Now to add to the confusion, the university I work for has decided to rename faculties to colleges, and schools to divisions. Why, I do not know. I speculate it is some weird attempt to make it appear more prestigious to new students who are more familiar with 'college' from watching too much US TV.

Comment: @Phil: [Harvard](http://www.harvard.edu/historical-facts) has been a university since 1780; I don't think this rule that universities were *systems* has ever been true on the east coast.

Comment: @PeterShor, I did say _usually_. I can remember when "university" usually meant a state college _system_, rather than a single institution. Institutions like Harvard or Yale that modeled themselves on places like Oxford or Cambridge might well have used "university" earlier than most.

Comment: In Massachusetts, before around 1970, the University of Massachusetts was the institution in Amherst, MA, while the other institutions that eventually became campuses of UMass were called by separate names (Lowell State, Boston State, etc.). Now, in California and NY, probably what @PhilPerry says has been true for a long time.

Comment: "The Three Lies of Harvard:"  http://www.summer.harvard.edu/blog-news-events/3-lies-harvard

Comment: I think the usual distinction between "college" and "university" involves the number of distinct _schools_, not the number of distinct _campuses_. Harvard considers itself to have become a university "in fact as well as name" in 1782, when it established a medical school within the same campus that housed the undergraduate college.

Comment: This distinction that universities are systems isn't even historically true. In California, aside from community colleges, they have two state-wide systems higher education systems. These were the "California State Colleges" and the "University of California" until 1972, when the "State Colleges" [got upgraded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_University) to "State Universities".

Answer (score 8):

The common distinction made is that universities offer graduate programs and colleges do not, but that is not entirely true. Many colleges do have graduate programs, but they are typically applied masters programs with little to no research components. The true distinction of a university is that universities have research programs and PhD programs. In fact, universities tend to put a lot of emphasis on research.

Due to the emphasis on research, it is not uncommon for classes at universities to be taught by TAs and grad students, this is especially true of entry-level classes. The larger the university, the more likely the lower-level classes will be taught by aids and students. At smaller colleges, however, the classes are generally taught by the actual professors.

As with most things, there are exceptions. There are smaller universities with less research emphasis and there are larger colleges that do have research components.

It is also useful to note that a college can be a division of a university. For instance, you could study under the College of Arts and Sciences at Cornell University. And, to further confuse things, sometimes these divisions are called "schools," such as the NYU Tisch School of Arts.

All that said, in the US it isn't pejorative to say that someone went to "college."

http://www.becker.edu/global/college-vs-university/

Comment: Does TAs stand for "Teaching Aids" ?

Comment: Teacher's Aids or Teacher's Assistants

Comment: At U.S. research universities TA means teaching assistant, who is almost always a master's or doctoral level student. A "UTA" or undergraduate TA is a (usually third or fourth year) student in a (4-year) bachelor's degree program.

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard an American refer to "university."  They say "college" just about exclusively.  This is regardless of whether the place they got their bachelors degree was actually a university or a college (also, as others have mentioned, sometimes "universities" are made up of smaller "colleges").  Literally the only times I've heard Americans say something like "when I was at University" is when they are talking to a foreigner.  It's always "when I was in college" or sometimes, "when I was in school" (if it's clear from the context that they are talking about college).

Likewise, nobody would ever say "university" to mean any kind of post-bachelors degree.  They'd say Med School, Business School, Grad School, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In many large American universities the "University" is the high-level organization and the "College" is the specific subordinate organization that focuses around a more specific area of study. It is common to see "University A, college of B". In common speech "Going to college" is what we say, but what we usually mean is "going to university".

The semantics are blurred today, mostly for reasons that have a political history behind them, but you can still see the original meanings in use at most American institutions older than 80 years or so.

Example: http://engineering.tamu.edu/cse/

Various headers read "Texas A&M University, College of Engineering" or just "College of Engineering", because that is a specific college within the Texas A&M structure. Within that college they have further subdivisions by "Department" (electrical engineering, computer science, etc.).

Some universities define a "college" as a specific campus location and focus there on a specific area of study. Some universities even call themselves a "university system" and each campus a "school" and each department a "college". The overall intent is that these terms imply a hierarchy, whether they are commonly used in that sense or not when speaking casually (and its worth noting that American nearly always speak casually, even on formal occasions).

Answer (score 0):

A college is a school that you go to for learning a skill for a job as an adult. For example, "I went to college to become an Engineer."

A University is a collection of colleges that have grouped together. If you look at a University website they will often ask, "What school would you like to apply for?" Here 'School' and 'College' are similar. They may say the 'College of Engineering' for example.

The idea of a University is to create the 'Universal Man'. Someone who is well educated in many areas of life. So when someone goes to University they are learning many things. If someone says 'College' they may mean something more specific, but a college most often is with other colleges making up a University.

Community Colleges are a bit of a stepping stone to a University as they may not have a large enough group of colleges to be officially called a University.

If you are talking with someone you cannot really be wrong by asking, "What college are you at?" That is a good open ended question to make good conversation, because they could answer with different kinds of answers.

Comment: OK, you went to college to become an engineer.  However, can you go to college to become a physician or a lawyer ?  If your answer is yes, then I understand what colleges and universities are. But if you say that one would have to go to University for that (Or Medical School/Law School) then I am really missing something.  Why could you go to college to become an engineer but not a physician ?

Comment: There is a difference between what the schools are actually called, and what people call them when they're talking about them.  The school you go to to become a physician could be technically called a college (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weill_Cornell_Medical_College) - but nobody would ever something like "when I was in college, getting my M.D.".  They would say "when I was in Med School...".

Comment: "College" as a general term ("I'm going to college next year" or "when I was in college") can only really refer to an undergraduate school, *regardless* of the official name of the medical school/law school/university where you're getting your phd or masters degree.