# When did 'College' change from meaning a "group of professionals" to a school for non-professionals?

Tags: meaning

The word 'College' is presumably related to *Collegial* and *Colleague*, originally referring to a group of professionals (not necessarily having anything to do with teaching). When did it change meaning entirely to mean **a school where people get an undergraduate degree**? This seems like quite a reversal.

Addition: based on a comment, the word 'college' seemed to shift from referring to the *people* involved, to the *institution*. This is reminiscent of the word 'church'. I wonder if there is a general term for this sort of shift? It also strikes the chord of how in the UK, a corporation or other body of people is primarily thought of as a *set of individuals* and in the USA it means a single entity. Maybe we are on to something here...

Comment: ***College:*** 
"body of scholars and students within a university," late 14c., from Old French college "collegiate body" (14c.), from Latin collegium "community, society, guild," literally "association of collegae" (see colleague). ***At first meaning any corporate group, the sense of "academic institution" attested from 1560s became the principal sense in 19c. via use at Oxford and Cambridge.*** http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=college&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: @Josh61 This appears to be the answer. I guess the word 'partner' passed it going the other way (from business sense to more general, including spouse). Funny that Oxford and Cambridge are actually *Universities*, aren't they?

Comment: In the United Kingdom, "college" can refer to either sixth form in the context of secondary education, or a constituent part of a university in the context of higher education. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/College

Comment: @Josh61  +1 for intelligent and informed responses to a, um... question.

Comment: @Josh61 I have no idea what a 'form' is. Doesn't the word 'grade' serve the purpose adequately? How are the students being formed?

Comment: Wow, *Gymnasium*. What an unholy mess we have made of language! Maybe we need more schools. Er, Colleges. Universities? Institutes?

Comment: [_sixth form_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_form_college); [_gymnasium_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnasium_(school))

Comment: @Gandalf Thank you. My point was that Gymnasium comes from Greece for *a place of physical AND mental training*. Germany apparently chose the mental aspect, and in the US Gym refers entirely to the physical aspect. (It is simply one period of the day in elementary school.) This is such a huge division, and so inscrutable, that I wonder how we all manage to communicate in any way.

Comment: God bless America.

Comment: @Gandalf Saved us from Germany.

Answer (score 2):

The OED's earliest entries for *college* are of

> An organized society of persons performing certain common functions and possessing special rights and privileges; a body of colleagues, a guild, fellowship, association

as in John Wyclif's *[The Clergy May Not Hold Property](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AEH6713.0001.001/432:28)*, ca. 1380:

> criste and his colage myȝt not be dispensid wiþ

in reference to the [Apostles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostle_(Christian)). Not long thereafter are found examples of its use to refer to any collective body, for example in John Capgrave's mid-15th century *Life of Saint Katherine*, at 1821:

> O Ihesu most swettest, whiche hast noumbred me Right in þi college a-mongis þi maydenes alle

Prominent among the various colleges in British society at the time were communities or corporations formed for mutual support: houses for clergy, for instance, or almshouses. An example given is [Morden College](http://www.mordencollege.org/), originally "an asylum for decayed merchants." In Chambers' *Cyclopædia*, similarly,the entry for *Colleges for disabled Soldiers, Seamen &c.* is a simple cross-reference: *See Hospitals*.

And so we find the OED's first entry for *college* as a community of scholars as follows:

> 4. A society of scholars incorporated within, or in connection with, a University, or otherwise formed for purposes of study or instruction:
>      a. *esp.* An independent self-governing corporation or **society (usually founded for the maintenance of poor students)** in a University, as the College of the Sorbonne in the ancient University of Paris, and the ancient colleges of Oxford and Cambridge.
>      b.  A foundation of the same kind, outside a University. (Often combining, in its original character, the functions of a local charity for the aged and of eleemosynary education for the young.)

(emphasis added). The earliest English-language entry given here is from about 1530: *In the Unyversyte Off Oxynfurde scho gert be A collage fowndyt*, in Andrew of Wyntoun's *Ðe orygynale cronykil of Scotland*.

Thence came the other meanings of college related to academia: as a synonym for university education in Scotland and the U.S. (as I [note elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66302/16052)), as subdivisions of universities, as institutions of advanced training, as buildings occupied by any of those bodies, and so forth.

Comment: So, once again, what began by referring to a group of individuals, ended referring to an institution. Is there a name for this? It seems to go on quite a lot. When the old and new meanings are both used, it seems rather ludicrous, like calling a group of people a building. (Or insisting that a corporation is a group of people, but I don't want to start a war.) You also indicate that 'college' went on to refer not just to a place, but a *condition*: education generally, or someone enrolled in a college ("college student"). These are yet more abstract.

Comment: It would seem to be straightforward metonymy to me, but I am not well-versed in all the classsifications of semantic shift.

Comment: George Orwell apparently said that we were making a hash of language and that it was affecting our ability to think. Perhaps he was right?

Answer (score -1):

During medieval times (500 - 1500), guilds were being formed in and around cities and towns. These guilds were composed of many different areas of work. Teaching during this period began specifically with Cathedral schools in which the teachers were priests/Bishops. Eventually, these places experienced an influx of students which led to the creation of specific buildings and campi for large amounts of students. These were considered to be a guild of their own and were called "Universitas." This is where we get our word "University".  In 1088 the first "Universitas" in Bologna, Italy was given a charter by Emperor Fredrick I making it an official guild that was to be accepted in the community.

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but I hope it gives you some insight to a synonym for college that would eventually lead to the words formation.

http://www.unibo.it/en/university