# What is the difference between teaches "at" and "in" xxx university

Tags: differences, prepositions, at-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which one is more correct: “works at a university” or “works in a university”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/which-one-is-more-correct-works-at-a-university-or-works-in-a-university)
>   [“In college” versus “at college” versus “at university”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66295/in-college-versus-at-college-versus-at-university)

He teaches at xxx University.
He teaches in xxx University.
What's the difference between at and in here?

Comment: I would use "at" at all because "in" has a tridimensional connotation that in your case seems awkard to my ear.

Comment: What is the use of linking as a possible duplicate a question that has been closed?

Comment: @MetaEd woops; didn't go deep enough.

Answer (score 6):

The sentence "he teaches at xxx University" implies that the individual in question is part of the university faculty. The sentence "he teaches in xxx University" is unidiomatic, but might mean "he teaches on the university grounds, but not officially, or not as part of the university faculty (perhaps he teaches at a daycare on the university campus).

Comment: I am from the US, and agree that "teaches at xxx University" is the way to say it here.  (James seems to be from Canada.)  But someone in UK, India, Australia, etc., should tell us the way to say it there...

Comment: Yes, _school, university_ or _college_ is a place, so it gets _at._ The _Department,_ however, is a container, so it gets _in_. _She teaches Galois Theory in the Mathematics Department at/of Southern North Dakota State University._

Comment: @John- I don't think a department is a container in today's schools. In your example that would be the correct way to say it, but if I wanted to say something about the department without putting it in another place, I would use at, assuming the department has more than one buildings? – Noah 6 mins ago

Comment: I just meant that metaphorically. Faculty teach **in** a department but **at** a school.