# "In school" vs "at school"

Tags: word-usage, at-in

I sometimes get confused whether to use *in* or *at*. For example,

> Children were not **at** school yesterday, because yesterday was a holiday.
>
> Children were not **in** school yesterday, because yesterday was a holiday.

Is there a rule of thumb to not confuse *in* and *at*?

Comment: We just as often say "have school" (AmE).  "The kids didn't have school yesterday because of the holiday."

Comment: Related: [“At the university” vs. “in the university”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not really, 'in school' is perhaps more common American English while 'at school' is more British but both are equally 'correct'. Similarly an American would probably say 'in college' while a Brit would say 'at university'.

**In** tends to be used for institutions, so you are 'in hospital' rather than 'at hospital' but 'at home' not 'in home' - although you might be put 'in a home'

It's just one of those things!

edit: there is perhaps a slight subtle difference that 'in school' means they attend school - as opposed to having finished school, while 'at school' means they are there now.
So "are your children in school" = are they under 16 or 18 ?
But "are your children at school" = are they at school today or are they at home.
(but that's from a BE perspective)

Comment: So, does it hurt your ears if you hear "Children were **at** school" or you wouldn't really notice the oversight?

Comment: @mgb My take (also BE) on your final point is that "in school" would only be used as you describe, but "at school" could be used in either instance: "he's not gone to university yet - he's still at/in school" and "he hasn't got home yet - he's still at school" all sound fine to me, but "he hasn't got home yet - he's still **in** school" would raise an eyebrow, since the implication is that the reason he's not home is that he's too young.

Answer (score 14):

Children who are ***at*** school are on the school grounds.

Children who are ***in*** school are in their classrooms.

(At least, those are the initial images that come to mind when I hear those two prepositions, and *try* to differentiate between them – although that differentiation is more forced than the norm).

In this case, either one will work just fine, because children who are at school (on the school grounds) are also, by default, in school (in their classrooms).  On a holiday, they are neither *in school* nor *at school*, so you can use either preposition without any loss of meaning.

The one exception may be if the football team had a Saturday practice.  In that case, I might say that David was *at* the school, but not *in* school – but that is a rare circumstance.  Normally, either word works fine for the examples you provided.

As far as other diffentiations go:

- I may be *at work*, but I'm never *in work* – unless I'm *lost in my work*.
- I may be *at home*, but I'm never *in home* – only *in my house*.
- I might speak *in jest*, but I would never speak *at jest*.
- I might be *at the restaurant*, but I could be *in the restaurant*.  *At the restaurant* would include being *in the parking lot*, but I probably wouldn't be *at the parking lot* –  unless we were *meeting at* the parking lot.

Maybe it just takes a little practice.  I'm reminded of this quip my father once told me:

> *The worms were eating in earnest.  Poor Ernest.*

Comment: I think that *on school grounds/in classrooms* distinction is spurious. As @mgb says, the primary difference is simply US/UK preference between essentially equivalent forms. Your other examples mostly concern specific idiomatic usages. You're *in work* if you have a job, but *at work* while you're working. Everyone speaks of being *at home*, never *in home*. For other contexts, *in* is usually more "spatially precise" than *at*, which can often mean simply "right next to" rather than "inside".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Precisely; good elaboration on what I tried to convey.  Macmillan list over 20 definitions and subdefinitions for [_at_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in), and more than 60 for [_in_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in), with the primary meaning of both exactly the same: "used for stating where someone or something is."  Ergo, I don't think there's any surefire "rule of thumb to not confuse _in_ and _at_," esp. with all their idiomatic forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: interestingly, you're *still at school* until school leaving age, but *still in school* till 4.15: the reverse of *at/in work*.

Comment: @TimLymington: It is rather odd - but as J.R. acknowledges, effectively unpredictable idiomatic usages abound in this area. Plus as we see from certain US/UK splits, often there's no universal agreement on which preposition to use, or what if any different meanings might be implied by either. I still think on average *"in"* is more "spatial" than *"at"* - it's just that some referents have multiple meanings (*school/work = education/employment*, as well as the buildings where those activities take place).

Comment: The in/at difference doesn't normally mean an indoors/outdoors in BE but is an institutional thing. You are 'in' school/prison/the army/hospital implies you are forced to attend. While 'at' generally just implies location, 'at' school/home/the seaside

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted one. (+1) :D

Comment: Both "at school" and "in school" can be used to refer to the period of one's life when one was enrolled in school, neither term always means physically present on school grounds. Context is everything.

Answer (score 7):

I've found the following answer in my high-school English grammar for Italian students (based on BE):

> Some nouns such as "school", "restaurant", "bank", "theatre",
>   "swimming pool", "café", etc. require either **at** or **in**,
>   depending on whether you consider the place for its function or its
>   material space.
>
> > "Jim is not here, he's **at** school." VS "There are 50 classrooms **in** the school."
> >
> > "Was Susan **at** the swimming pool with you?" VS "Is John already **in** the swimming pool?"
> >
> > "They are having a snack **at** a café." VS "She was sitting **in** a café."

Comment: The "function VS material space" is a great way of looking at it! (+1) :P

Answer (score 2):

I think another distinction to add here, just because nobody seems to have mentioned it, is that the word "school" has different meanings in AE and BE.  In the US, if somebody is "still in school" that really just means (s)he is studying somewhere, maybe in high school, maybe in medical school, who knows.  In my understanding, BE speakers use "school" to mean secondary school, never college/university.

Comment: *School* also means primary school. You're right that it does not mean college or university.