# Can we say, "She teaches English IN a highschool in China" or "She teaches English AT a highschool in China"?

Tags: differences, prepositions

I tried searching for the answers and it says that when you say *at* it generally talks about the location. When we say *in* it talks about when you're inside that place. I just don't know which one is better. I hope you can help me.

Comment: I assume from the question that one of them was meant to read _at a high school_. I (BrE) would say _at a school_, but I wouldn't regard _in_ as wrong.

Comment: ELU: [“In school” vs “at school”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63772/in-school-vs-at-school). [***English Language Learners***:](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) *Preposition confusion - Do you learn somthing '**at**' school OR '**in**' school?*

Comment: They mean essentially the same thing.  Even if one is speaking of a remote learning situation, they would likely be understood metaphorically.

Comment: If she teaches English in the schoolyard, then only one of the sentences is correct …