# Are "in" and "at" the same in some situations?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

If someone calls me, and I say I can't talk to them at the moment, because I'm at school, is there any difference between the following two sentences?

> - I'm at school.
> - I'm in school.

Do they convey the same meaning or they are different?

Comment: Please see ["at university" vs. "in university"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/studying-phd-at-the-university-or-studying-phd-in-the-university), ["in school" vs. "at school"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63772/in-school-vs-at-school), ["in college" vs. "at college"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66295/in-college-versus-at-college-versus-at-university), or just browse our [dedicated tag for *at* vs. *in*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/at-in?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I'm in school"* means that you are actually attending school; that is, you are at school during school hours and doing an activity related to school. *"I'm at school"* means that you're at the place where you attend school, but you may or may not be attending school. For your sentence, if somebody says

> I can't talk because I'm in/at school,

presumably they are busy because they are attending school, so in this context they have the same meaning. For a different context, they are different. For example:

> I missed the bus; I'm still at school. Could you come pick me up?

You wouldn't use *in school* in that sentence.