# Sixth year of Ph.D. program/career

Tags: word-choice

What is the best word to use for Ph.D. in the following sentence:

"I am in the sixth year of my Ph.D. program/career."

Comment: Is a Ph.D. a 'career"? Isn't it a course,  a study, or simply "doing a P.h.D"?

Comment: Closely related: [“Studying PhD at the university” or “studying PhD in the university”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/studying-phd-at-the-university-or-studying-phd-in-the-university)

Comment: "I am in the sixth year of my Ph.D. studies." But is that really true? Were the first 3 or 4 years **undergraduate** studies? How about "I am studying for my Ph.D." and reveal your progress later in the text.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the adjective form for Ph.D. I think the term you are looking for is *doctoral*; the full sentence which sounds most natural to me is:

"I am in the sixth year of my doctoral program."

Unless there are regional usages I am not familiar with, it would be unusual to refer to a Ph.D. as a career. If you want to emphasize the career aspect (perhaps independent of any one particular program), then that would use the term *academic*, giving you the sentence:

"I am in the sixth year of my academic career."

One final note: I normally only see people refer to their academic career time frame as starting after their doctoral studies are finished.